# Wordpress new output by category plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have two columns, both columns are for news, but I want  to output the news by category: the first column should contain one category and the second column should contain a different one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a plug-in, but a page tempate.

First, in the template, write the HTML and CSS for your two columns. A very basic template could look like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="column1">
</div>

<div id="column2">
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now you'll pull in the appropriate posts for each column of your layout. Instead of having one WordPress loop which shows your posts, you’ll have multiple loops on the page, one for each column/area.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
...
<?php endwhile;?>
```

E.g., in your blog you'll have one in each column.

Before each loop, we need to tell WordPress which posts to display. We add one line of code, which will look something like this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1&showposts=10'); ?>
```

In that example, it’ll pull in 10 posts from category 1. If I wanted to show posts from two categories (as I do on my blog), it’ll be something like:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1,2&showposts=10'); ?>
```

If you want to show everything but category 1, use:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-1'); ?>
```

You can do a lot with query_posts.

Finally, you'll add whatever you want to your loops in terms of displaying particular content. For example:

```
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
```

A full example might look like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="column1">
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></small>
<div class="entry">
<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<div id="column2">
<?php query_posts('cat=2'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></small>
<div class="entry">
<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates and http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action for more info.